# Network Bandwidth aggregation

Tags: networking, tcp, linux-kernel, network-programming

Lets say I have access to two different networks: A and B. My device has two different network interfaces N1 and N2.

A has a bandwidth of 5 mbps
B has a bandwidth of 3 mbps

I want to combine these two Networks to get a total bandwidth of: 8 Mbps.
The way I was thinking of doing it as follows:

I use the two network Interfaces(N1, N2) to connect to the networks A, B.
Lets say I have hundred packets to send. I send 50 packets using network A and 50 using network B. I send these packets to a personal server where packets coming from network A and B are combined and are sent to the intended location.

In order to do all this I think I will have to get all traffic from the network layer and send it to different interfaces.

Assuming everything I just mentioned is doable, I want to know how can I intercept the packets coming from the internet layer so that I can implement the above logic and channel the traffic to different interfaces.

Comment: I assume somebody downvoted because you don't show what research you've done. Have you looked this up on other sites? Can you include any info you've found? I think it's an interesting question and I'll upvote it if you include research you've done.

Answer (score 0):

I would say: this is more like a question for https://unix.stackexchange.com/ **but**, just in case, let me give you a tip: this is achieved using iproute2's multipath capability. At least, a few years back.

https://lartc.org/howto/lartc.rpdb.multiple-links.html

Comment: Thank you! I will ask this question on https://unix.stackexchange.com/